# Proving that restricting the range of a continuous function preserves continuity

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Suppose that $f : X \to Y$ is continuous.
Let the image set $f(X) = {f(x) | x \in X}$ be a proper subspace of
$Y$. Prove that $f : X → f(X)$ is continuous

How do I prove this using the definition of continuity?

Comment: Hint: what will the topology on $f(X)$ be?

Answer (score 3):

A function $f:(X,\tau) \rightarrow (Z, \tau_1)$ is continuous if for every open set $G \in \tau_1$, $f^{-1}[G] \in \tau$.

You have $Z= f(X)$. The open sets in $f(X)$ are the $H_i \cap f(X)$ with $H_i$ open in $Y$ and for every $H_i$ one has $f^{-1}[H_i]$ open because $f$ is continuous.

Now $f^{-1}[H_i \cap f(X)]=f^{-1}[H_i] \cap f^{-1}[f(X)]=f^{-1}[H_i] \cap X$. (The last equality is because for every set $X$ and every function $f$, one has $X\subseteq  f^{-1}[f(X)]$, and here $X$ is the whole set, so $X\subseteq  f^{-1}[f(X)]$ implies $X =  f^{-1}[f(X)]$). Then as $f^{-1}[H_i]$ and $X$ are open, their intersection is open, so $f^{-1}[H_i \cap f(X)]$ is open and $f:X \rightarrow f(X)$ is continuous.